# Finding the determinant of $x*x^{t}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I would like to know what the determinant of $x*x^t$ where $t$ denotes the transpose of the vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$

Would appreciate any hint on how to find the determinant

Comment: Hint: Every row/column is a scalar multiple of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $n>1$. If this is the case, then $xx^T$ is an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), and thus this matrix will have rank $1$ provided $x\neq 0$. Since the rank is $1<n$, the matrix does not have rank $n$. Hence, the matrix $xx^T$ is not invertible and therefore has determinant $0$. Obviously if $x=0$ then this is the zero matrix which has determinant $0$. Also, if $n=1$, then the determinant of $xx^T$ is simply the single entry of $x$ squared.

Answer (score 3):

Since $xx^{T}$ is a rank-1 matrix, the determinant will be 0, except for the very special case where $x$ is a one element vector.